# How to save dynamic textbox value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dynamic table populated with textboxs.

**.aspx**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div id="divChaves" runat="server">
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Control> textBox in allTextBoxs)
   divChaves.Controls.Add(textBox.Value as Control);
```

With this code I can load my textboxs on the div, but when I try to save the page and take what was written on them, I'm not able.

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Control> textBox in allTextBoxs)
{
    TextBox txtKey = (TextBox)textBox.Value.Controls[0];
    string textValue = Request.Form[txtKey.UniqueID];
    //manipulate my textValue
}
```

This is what I need to use to can take the `textBox.Text` that I load dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If I get the question right....

Loop through the textbox controls in the placeholder/control

```
foreach (TextBox tb in divChaves.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
    string text = tb.Text;
    // Do whatever 
}
```

Comment: the problem is `divChaves` doesn't have textboxs reference. I create the textboxs, save on a hashtable and put on the div. When I postback, div lost the reference for txts..

Comment: Sounds to me like you are missing a `if(IsPostBack)` on the form load